# python 2.7.6 inputing a number and getting a script to output the written form using recurrsion, how is this possible?

Tags: python-2.7, recursion

I have to create a script for class that takes a user input number and the script needs to output the written form of that number. This needs to be done using recursion. When I run the script that I have copied below it doesn't work, I'm not sure what the issue is. It also needs to use the same lists for upper level numbers like the tens of thousands and above. I am fairly clueless on how to make all of this work. What do I need to fix to make this script work?

```
number = input ('Please enter an integer ')
def name(number):
  list1 = ["zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven",
           "eight", "nine", "ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen",
           "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"]
  list2 = ["", "", "twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy",
       "eighty", "ninety"]

  list3 = ['', "", 'one-hundred', 'two-hundred', 'three-hundred', 'four-hundred', 'five-hundred' , 'six-hundred', 'seven-hundred', 'eight-hundred', 'nine-hundred']
  if number < 20:
      return list1[number]

  if number < 100:
    return list3[list2[number]]

   hundreds_digit = number * 10
   tens_digit = number / 10
   ones_digit = number % 10

  if ones_digit == 0:
    return list2[tens_digit]
  else:
return list2[tens_digit] + "-" + list1[ones_digit]

  if tens-digit == 0:
     return list3[hundreds_digit]
  else:
     return list3[hundreds_digit] + '-' + list2[tens_digit] + "-" + list1[ones_digit]




################
# Main Program #
################

 name(number)
```

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you want to achieve and the code is messy. Start by copying the way, Python code is usually written (using `main` function, and calling it when not being imported, what is tested by so common piece of code like `if __name__ == "__main__":`

Answer (score 0):

This is what I have got so far, but it can be improved since giving `111` as the input returns `one-hundred ten one`.

```
def hundreds(num):
        obj = {1:'one-hundred', 2: 'two-hundred', 3:'three-hundred', 4:'four-hundred', 5:'five-hundred', 6:'six-hundred', 7:'seven-hundred', 8:'eight-hundred', 9:'nine-hundred'}
        return obj[int(num)]

def tens(num):
        obj = {1:"ten", 2:"twenty", 3:"thirty", 4:"forty", 5:"fifty", 6:"sixty", 7:"seventy",8:"eighty", 9:"ninety"}
        return obj[int(num)]

def ones(num):
        obj = {1:"one", 2:"two", 3:"three", 4:"four", 5:"five", 6:"six", 7:"seven", 8:"eight", 9:"nine"}
        return obj[int(num)]

def written_form(num):
    if len(str(num)) <= 0:
            return False
    else:
            if len(str(num)) == 3:
                    print hundreds(str(num)[0]),
                    try:
                            num = int(''.join(list(str(num))[1:]))
                    except ValueError:
                            return
                    written_form(num)
            elif len(str(num)) == 2:
                    print tens(str(num)[0]),
                    try:
                            num = int(''.join(list(str(num))[1:]))
                    except ValueError:
                            return
                    written_form(num)
            elif len(str(num)) == 1:
                    print ones(str(num)[0]),
                    try:
                            num = int(''.join(list(str(num))[1:]))
                    except ValueError:
                            return
                    written_form(num)

def main():
        var = int(raw_input('Enter your number: '))
        written_form(var)
```

I have three functions to get the hundreds, tens, and ones value of the number, by using a dictionary:

```
>>> def hundreds(num):
...         obj = {1:'one-hundred', 2: 'two-hundred', 3:'three-hundred', 4:'four-hundred', 5:'five-hundred', 6:'six-hundred', 7:'seven-hundred', 8:'eight-hundred', 9:'nine-hundred'}
...         return obj[int(num)]
... 
>>> hundreds(6)
'six-hundred'
>>> hundreds(4)
'four-hundred'
>>>
```

In the 'main' function (*`written_form()`*), we break the function if the length of `num` is less than or equal to 0. If not, then if the length is 3, we print the hundreds value of the first number, and then remove the first number from the integer, and we keep going from there.

This program runs as:

```
bash-3.2$ python written_form.py
Enter your number: 789
seven-hundred eighty nine
bash-3.2$ python written_form.py
Enter your number: 156
one-hundred fifty six
bash-3.2$ python written_form.py
Enter your number: 999
nine-hundred ninety nine
bash-3.2$ python written_form.py
Enter your number: 631
six-hundred thirty one
bash-3.2$
```

Hope this helps!